# How to use variables using scss partials on ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I created a new rails app. I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and Rails 6.0.2.1.

I downloaded a bootstrap template on startbootstrap.com and trying to use it for my landing page. So i copied the css & scss files inside *app/assets/stylesheets*, and i copied the HTML.

I have the following partials in *app/assets/stylesheets* : _variables.scss and _call-to-action.scss.

In the same directory, i also have the file **application.scss** with the following code :

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
@import "variables";
@import "call-to-action";
```

I have the following code in the partial **_call-to-action.scss** :

```
.call-to-action {
  background-color: $gray-800;
  background: url('../images/bg-masthead.jpg');
}
```

I have the following code in the partial **_variables.scss** :

```
$white: #fff !default;
$gray-800: #343a40 !default;
$black: #000 !default;
```

And when i go to my landing page, i have the following error :

```
SassC::SyntaxError in Pages#home
Showing /home/user/code/myusername/rails-project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

Error: Undefined variable: "$gray-800".
        on line 4:21 of app/assets/stylesheets/_call-to-action.scss
>>   background-color: $gray-800;
```

As my partials files are imported on *application.scss*, i don't understand how to solve this issue. Did i do something wrong ?

---

EDIT : i removed require_tree and require_self syntax but now i get 500 internal server error. I have this when i check the development.log :

```
> tail -f log/development.log

rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SCSS imports you don't want to use the `require_tree` and `require_self` syntax. This is fine alone:

```
 @import "variables";
 @import "call-to-action";
```

Comment: I just did it, but now i have `500 Internal Server Error`
How can i check the logs ?

Comment: In the file log/development.log